# How to do a query like [a between (...) or b between (..) ] in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have some records like

{
PKey,
...,
startTime,
endTime
}

I need to query all data with starttime or endtime within a date range.

With SQL i can do this select * from table where startTime between (a, b) or endTime between (a, b).

So how to do this in dynamodb?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.